# Are XMPP PubSub notifications broadcasted simultaneously or queue like?

Tags: xmpp, publish-subscribe

I want to know whether xmpp publish-subscribe functionality send notifications to all subscribers simultaneously(broadcasts) or sends notifications in a queue i.e. one by one.

I want to know the difference between pub-sub and jaxl class which i am using because the jaxl sends push messages in queue that is one user at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the implementation. Bare [XEP-0060 PubSub](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0060.html) implementation would send separate `event` notification `message`s to all subscribers.

However, there are other extensions such as [XEP-0033 Extended Stanza Addressing](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0033.html) that allows multicast addressing of `message`s.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for replying.
Please confirm whether i am getting this correct the xep-0060 XEP-0060 PubSub would send notification messages in queue i.e. one by one and XEP-0253 PubSub Chaining will send notifications simulatneously.

Comment: I misread the pubsub chaining spec when skimming through it. Updated my answer. I'm only using xmpp thru 3rd party APIs, not on protocol level :P